# Very close to having a working django frontpage and Im not sure what is wrong

Tags: python, django

Im close to being able to spin up and iterate on this django website that I am trying to launch.
I seem to be struggling with alternating 404 and 500 errors presenting as each of these two:

```
[24/Nov/2023 11:19:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145
[24/Nov/2023 11:20:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 179
```

respectively

When I alternate my urls.py line 20 between

```
path('randoplant_home', views.randoplant_home, name='randoplant_home'),   # 404
path('', views.randoplant_home, name='randoplant_home'),                  # 500
```

I don't quite know what else I am missing to be able to spin up my app and I've not been able to isolate what is causing my code to still error.

here is my project structure:

```
randoplant/
├── frontend/
│   ├── templates/
│   │   └── randoplant_home.html
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── ...
├── views.py
├── urls.py
├── settings.py
└── ...
```

here is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('randoplant_home/', views.randoplant_home, name='randoplant_home'),
    #path('', views.randoplant_home, name='Home')
]
```

and my views.py

```
def randoplant_home(request):
    return render(request, 'frontend/templates/randoplant_home.html')

####################### MANAGEMENT #################################

class PlantPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'randoplant_home.html'
```

Very close to spinning up my home page for the first time but Im really not sure what else is missing.

Comment: If you get an 500, if DEBUG is True, you should get a detailed error message.

Comment: This was super helpful and i eventually got my site to spin up!